# adding a custom jquery.validation method results in Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, unobtrusive-validation

I am battling to get jquery.validation to work with a custom method.

I am trying this

```
 $.validator.addMethod("validateMe", function (value, element) {
        alert("validate");
    });
$( "#myTextBox" ).rules( "add", {
    validateMe: true
  });
```

I am using jquery.validate v1.12 but when trying to validate I get an error of

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: You found a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone else has the same problem it turns out I wasnt providing a message

```
 $.validator.addMethod("validateMe", function (value, element) {
    alert("validate");
 }, 'Hello message!');
```

did the trick